# connection to analysis service by excel using integrated security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have excel which connects to analysis service by http://localhost:port/xmla that connect to jetty server which is running on diff server. I want to enable window authentication that will user details for window active directory send to the server to validate.

But the problem if I using radio button that is "use window auth" it is not sending the credential to the server.

To do that we need to enable window integrated security.

I want to know in which layer the credential will be authenticated do we need to write ntlm protocol logic at server side or do we have to write any code to windows level.

Thanks in advance, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the SSAS to use AD for users. Then you need to add the active directory users to the Cube you are trying to access. You can either create a role and add the users there or you can add the directly to the cube security. The users are added with domain\sAMAccountName to the SSAS. Then to authenticate you use the sAMAccountName and the password (if you created the users manually the username and the sAMAccountName are usually the same).

In excel you write the credentials either in the connection string or in the dialog that it shows. And you input something like

Server: http://localhost/xmla

User: Domain\sAMAccountName (from the AD)

Password: the password :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. In the current implementation we are able to login to the running jetty server via excel->data->from other source->from analysis Service: it will promt with two option one is to use window auth and enter uid/pwd. So when we are entring manually uid/pwd its working and its hitting the authentication servlet and able to validate the user. but we dont want to put uid/pwd manually we want to use the "use window auth" so we dont ve to enter uid/pwd and when submit it should hit the authentication servlet and then ve can validate the user on server side.